# Clone on loop problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple file upload where on drag and drop id like to clone 4 inputs fields (filename, alternative texts) foreach, i tried different ways.
But the problem is it got cloned much more often than it should.

In my example on Jsfiddle i simulated with 5 files, but it get cloned ~15 times instead of 4 times.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var  lol = 5;

  for (var i = 0; i < lol; i++) {   
    if(i > 0){
     var $newCustomer = $('#clonemulti').clone();
      $newCustomer.removeAttr('id');

      $newCustomer.insertAfter( ".clonemulti" );  
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clonemulti" id="clonemulti">         
    <input type="text"  class="filenameauto" name="filename[]" placeholder="" title="Dateiname" maxlength="20" required>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Alt. Text (de)" name="alttext[]" maxlength="50" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Alt. Text (it)" name="alttext[]" maxlength="50" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Alt. Text (en)" name="alttext[]" maxlength="50" required>

    <br/><br/>
</div> 
<button>clone</button>
```

Comment: I've converted your JS fiddle in to an executable snippet (if the edit is approved). Please try not to rely on off-site references to demonstrate your problem. Instead, please include all code relevant to your problem in your question (ideally in the form of a stack [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `.insertAfter(".clonemulti")` is adding the new rows after *every* existing `.clonemulti` element.

To achieve what you require change the selector so you instead insert them after the last instance of that element:

```
$newCustomer.insertAfter(".clonemulti:last");
```

Also note that your `if (i > 0)` condition is redundant when you can just initialise `i` to `1` in the loop. Here's a full example of the updated JS:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var lol = 5;

  for (var i = 1; i < lol; i++) {
    var $newCustomer = $('#clonemulti').clone();
    $newCustomer.removeAttr('id');
    $newCustomer.insertAfter(".clonemulti:last");
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh dear, thanks a lot. I tried to set :last on the clone element .. wich wasnt working. But ur solution works, thanks again.